# How to repeat div element n times in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I duplicate a `<div>` so there are n copies using JavaScript?

**Start with 1:**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**End up with 5:**

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: @SajadAbedi my friend, you should show us what you've tried so far with JavaScript - you're more likely to get people to help you out in that case.

Answer (score 14):

Using the pure JS [node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

```js
function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
    for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
        copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
    }
}

multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.box'), 5, true);
```

Pass `true` as third argument to `multiplyNode` to copy child nodes too.

[Here's a demo.](http://jsbin.com/zijeho/1/edit?html,js,output)

Edit:

With ES6 condensed syntax, the above example becomes:

```
const node = document.querySelector('.box');
[...Array(5)].forEach(_ => node.parentNode.insertBefore(node.cloneNode(true), node));
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the fiddle to get your result

https://jsfiddle.net/dcpg4v1c/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++)
     $("#dvMain").append("<div class='row'>Test</div>");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dvMain'></div>
```

Comment: I'll be generous and give what you (and everyone else here) deserve (an upvote)! :D

Answer (score 3):

Create a container div with a id and place `<div class="box"></div>` inside it. Then using jQuery you can run a loop for desired number of time and append divs like

```
jQuery("#container_div_id").append(jQuery("#container_div_id").children().first().clone())
```

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q2udhgx/)

Answer (score 1):

im using jquery here. You can place div parent as i used in example "divRepeat"

```
<div id="divRepeat">
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

in Jquery

```
for(var i=0;i<("how many repeat do you want");i++){
   $("#divRepeat").append($(".box").html());
   //you can add other logic here, like you want diferent id or class to add in new box
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Make use of `php` with apache server, change the extension from `.html` to `.php` and use:

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo "<div id='box'></div>";
}

?>
```