# What is the syntax of sending parameters in <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

In the given code I am trying to add a dynamic ID to a div inside the `foreach` loop on the basis of var `i`.

However, I can't find the correct syntax, and the same issue is in the calling jQuery function. I am trying to send the parameter `i` to the `DeleteCurrentImage` function. Please guide me. Thank you. This code is written in MVC .cshtml file.

```
<div id="filesList">
  @foreach (var item in imgArray)
  {
    var i = 0;
    <div class="img101 floatleft" id="img101_' + i + '">
      <img src="@item" />
      <a href="#" id="DeleteCurrentImage" onclick="DeleteCurrentImage('+ i +');">Delete</a>
    </div>
    i += 1;
  }
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to include JS directly into the HTML / vica versa, this can't be done in standard JS, you'll instead need to use an included Javascript file. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30268827/1592783

Comment: no i am not, this code is written in MVC, .cshtml file. using razor syntax

Comment: i am trying to add the iteration variable "i" to the div ID and to thy function parameter of jquery function. this functions definition is written at the bottom of this cshtml page.

Comment: Fair enough, however you edited your question after I posted that response to mention it was a cshtml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this fixes:

1. Initiliaze `i` outside the foreach;
2. Into the cicle append every item with the call to the function passing the id (preced by `#` id selector)
3. In the function Delete the wanted element by the passed `id`
4. Increase i

   ```
   <div id="filesList">
       @{
           var i = 0;
           foreach (var item in imgArray) 
           {             
               <div class="img101 floatleft" id="img101_@(i)">
                   <img src="@item" />
                   <a href="#" onclick="DeleteCurrentImage('#img101_@(i)');">Delete</a>
               </div>
               i++;
           }
       }
       <div style="clear: both"></div>
   </div>
   <script>
       function DeleteCurrentImage(item) {
           // Delete the element
           $(item).remove();
       }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: i++ needs to go into the foreach

Comment: Right @BryanVam! i missed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

`i` is a variable in your C# code, so you need to output it to the HTML on the server side, not from JS. You can do that like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="DeleteCurrentImage(@i);">Delete</a>
```

Note I removed the `id` attribute here as you were creating duplicates which is invalid.

That being said, it's a much better idea to use unobtrusive event handlers instead of `on*` event attributes. Then you can simply traverse the DOM to find the content related to the element which raised the event, without needing to generate any unique `id` attributes.  As you've tagged the question with jQuery you can achieve that like this:

```html
<div id="filesList">
  @foreach (var item in imgArray) 
  { 
    <div class="img101 floatleft">
      <img src="@item" />
      <a href="#" class="DeleteCurrentImage">Delete</a>
    </div>
  }
  <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.DeleteCurrentImage').click(function() {
  $(this).prev('img').remove();
});
```

Note that this removes the sibling `img` element. If you want to remove the entire containing `div`, change `.prev('img')` to `.closest('div')`