# How to .clone() elements according to input number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to clone elements according to an input number. So if I select 1, I'll have one cloned element, if I select 2, I'll have two cloned elements.

I've tried with `$("elementtoclone").clone().appendTo("clonecontainer")` and it work, but just the first time, because when I select another number, it just append another clon. For example, If I select 1, I'll have that one, but after if I select 2 I'll have three but I just need two.

So I've been thinking that the logic way to do this is using the .html() method instead appendTo().

So I need something like this:

```js
function letsClone(times){
  var clons;
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++){
    clons = clons + $("#original").clone();
  }
  $("#clonecontainer").html(clons);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" onchange="letsClone(this.value)">

<div id="original"><p>I'm gonna be cloned</p></div>

<div id="clonecontainer" style="border:1px solid red">

</div>
```

But that obviously doesn't work because that's how I add strings, not DOM elements.

So is there a way to add that cloned elements to a variable and then using the .html() method to show them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repeat div element n times in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267973/how-to-repeat-div-element-n-times-in-html)

Comment: I'm not agree with you @VigneshRaja , can you specify which one of those answers solves my question?

Comment: It has a logic that would help you. It multiplies the node it self. Here the inner element is cloned inside the outer element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the html of `#clonecontainer` in each function call. I will also prefer *oninput* instead of *onchange*.

I believe you want clone only the *p* element from `#original`.

```js
function letsClone(times){ 
  $("#clonecontainer").html('');
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++){
    var clons = $("#original > p").clone();
    $("#clonecontainer").append(clons);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" oninput="letsClone(this.value)">

<div id="original"><p>I'm gonna be cloned</p></div>

<div id="clonecontainer" style="border:1px solid red">

</div>
```

**If you really want to clone the whole `#original`**

***Please Note:*** the attribute [`Element.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) must be unique in a document, use *class* instead. In that case to clone use the `first()` of the class.

You can try the following way:

```js
function letsClone(times){ 
  $("#clonecontainer").html('');
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++){
    var clons = $(".original").first().clone();
    $("#clonecontainer").append(clons);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" oninput="letsClone(this.value)">

<div class="original"><p>I'm gonna be cloned</p></div>

<div id="clonecontainer" style="border:1px solid red">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very simple to fix. Please add  `.html()` when clone `$("#original").clone().html();`, because `.html()` require a string, but `$("#original").clone()` is an element jQuery, so it is undefined, and you cannot use operator `+` for jQuery object.

`.html()` return string of jQuery object.

This is solution

```js
function letsClone(times){
  var clons = "";
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++){
    clons = clons + $("#original").clone().html();
  }
  $("#clonecontainer").html(clons);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" onchange="letsClone(this.value)">

<div id="original"><p>I'm gonna be cloned</p></div>

<div id="clonecontainer" style="border:1px solid red">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Append the html of the element repeatedly and replace the parent's html.

**Note**: The `>0` check is needed else it leads to an infinite loop

```js
function letsClone(times)
{
    var html = $("#original").html();
    while(--times > 0)
    {
        html += html;
    }
    $("#clonecontainer").html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" onchange="letsClone(this.value)">
<div id="original"><p>I'm gonna be cloned</p></div>
<div id="clonecontainer" style="border:1px solid red"></div>
```

It can also be simplified to a single line. Using [String.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) on the html string.

**Note**: IE don't support it.

```js
function letsClone(times)
{
    $("#clonecontainer").html($("#original").html().repeat(times));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" onchange="letsClone(this.value)">
<div id="original"><p>I'm gonna be cloned</p></div>
<div id="clonecontainer" style="border:1px solid red"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you add it to the same div:

```js
function letsClone(times){ 
  $("#clonecontainer").html('');
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++){
   var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];
  var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
  $("#clonecontainer").append(cln);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" oninput="letsClone(this.value)">

<div class="original"><p>I'm gonna be cloned</p></div>

<div id="clonecontainer" style="border:1px solid red">

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

If you need it in multi Div

```js
function letsClone(times){ 
  $("#clonecontainer").html('');
  
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++){
   var elmnt = document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[i];
  var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
 
document.getElementById("clonecontainer").appendChild(cln)
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" oninput="letsClone(this.value)">

<div id="original" class="original"><p>I'm gonna be cloned</p></div>

<div id="clonecontainer" style="border:1px solid red">

</div>




</body>
</html>
```