# How to avoid repeating class names of columns

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I currently define a grid as follows with each "column" or div having repeating elements. Is there a way to not have to repeat the set on each div?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-sm-12">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-sm-12">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-sm-12">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 col-sm-12">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not without a script. Can you generate them in a loop on the backend? If so, please tag your stack. Do they always have the same content?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267973/how-to-repeat-div-element-n-times-in-html