# How do I insert elements that repeats themselves in HTML using just Javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

[image]> I have this yellow box (with class="yellow-box") , and a small blue

> box (with class="box-1") inside it. I need 12 times the same div in
>   HTML with JavascriptDOM - without hardcoding in HTML by typing 12
>   times the same div.
>
> HTML code

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Match the box</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <script src="boxGame.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body class="background-img">
            <div class="yellow-box">
              <div class="box-1"> </div>


            </div>

        </body>
    </html>



 .background-img {
    background-image: url("fundal.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.yellow-box {
    background-color: yellow;
   width: 850px;
   height: 600px;
   margin: auto;
   top: 30px;
   position: relative;

}

.box-1 {
    background-color: blue;
   width: 160px;
   height: 120px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   margin: 25px;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat div element n times in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267973/how-to-repeat-div-element-n-times-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your javascript file, or inside your script tag:

```
let outerDiv = document.querySelector('.yellow-box');

for(let i = 0; i++; i<=12 ){
    let boxDiv = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'box-1');

    outerDiv.appendChild(boxDiv);
}
```