# Remove (not hide) overflow of many divs from container, or constrain amount to container?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a background that adds and removes square divs based on the size of the container, which is affected by resizing the window.

To add the divs, I followed the examples on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267973/how-to-repeat-div-element-n-times-in-html). But, resizing the screen continues to multiply the number of divs. Is there a way to constrain the amount of squares to the size of the container, or to remove the overflow?

(I don't want to simply css overflow:hidden because that doesn't solve the problem of a billion divs being multiplied.) And I'm an absolute javascript newbie, so bear with me!

```
let contain = document.getElementById("squareContain");
let width = contain.offsetWidth;
let height = contain.offsetHeight;
var containerArea = width * height;
var canAdd = Math.floor(containerArea/1600); //For 40px x 40px squares

function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
    for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
        copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
    }
}

$(window).on("resize", function(){
    multiplyNode(document.querySelector('.square'), canAdd, false);
}).resize();
```

Edit [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/i_need_help_please/hjy78k3d/18/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you only calculate how many squares fit once, but you need recalculate each time window size changed:

```js
let contain = document.getElementById("squareContain");
function canAdd()
{
  let square = contain.children[0],
      cWidth = contain.offsetWidth,
      cHeight = contain.offsetHeight,
      sWidth = square.offsetWidth,
      sHeight = square.offsetHeight;

  return Math.floor(cWidth / sWidth) * Math.floor(cHeight / sHeight);
}
function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
    if (contain.children.length == count)
      return;

    if (contain.children.length < count)
    {
      for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
          copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
          node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      while(contain.children.length > count)
      {
        contain.removeChild(contain.children[contain.children.length -1]);
      }
    }
}

$(window).on("resize", function(){
  multiplyNode(contain.querySelector('.square'), canAdd(), false);
}).resize();
```

```css
.square_container{
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}
.square{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="squareContain" class="square_container">
    <div class="square"></div><!--...etc...-->
</div>
```

Comment: I agree that it ought to recalc every time the window is changed, but this example still overflows the container if the window is shrunk. I wonder if I need to rethink the multiplyNode function, or make an if statement?

Comment: @i_need_help_please, I've updated the code