# jQuery new divs won't animate with $(document).on

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So, I had an animation function. It worked. You hover over some squares, they leave a little trail and then fade back:

```
 $(".square").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationend", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("squareAnim");  
});

$(".square").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("squareAnim");        
});
```

```
.squareAnim {
    animation-name: changeColor;
    animation-duration: 4s;
  }

  @keyframes changeColor {
    0% {background-color: rgb(5, 5, 5);}
    25% {background-color: rgba(255, 5, 20);}
    50% {background-color: rgba(20, 5, 255);}
    100% {background-color: rgb(5, 5, 5);}
  }
```

Later, I decided I needed to add/remove squares based on the page size. I got help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67224772/remove-not-hide-overflow-of-many-divs-from-container-or-constrain-amount-to-c).

Welp, I had to change the animation function because it's bind and won't work on new divs. I researched and tried different functions, and this is where I'm at now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationend", ".square", function(){
      $(this).removeClass("squareAnim");
    });
    $(document).on("hover", ".square", function(){
      $(this).addClass("squareAnim");
    });
});
```

But, it's not working. I don't know if `$(document).ready` is redundant (it was my attempt at delegation) but it still doesn't work with or without it. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/i_need_help_please/h2gq4fcx/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rebind the events when you create the elements (i.e. `onresize`). It will not propagate to newly created elements if you just bind it once `onready`.

Also, `onhover` is deprecated (removed in jQuery 1.9) and should be replaced with `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave.`

From [jQuery's docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  multiplyNode(contain.querySelector('.square'), canAdd(), false);
  $(document).on("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationend", ".square", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("squareAnim");
  });
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".square", function() {
    $(this).addClass("squareAnim");
  });
}).resize();
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0op26fdt/)